# SIGKill Without warning or stack trace with NSLogv

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I know this is a somewhat vague question, but during debug execution, the app I'm working on dies without any stacktrace or warning and with simply this message in the debug console:

> Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”.

I have NSZombieEnabled, NSDebugEnabled, MallocStackLoggingNotCompact and MallocStackLogging all set within XCode.

I've run Instruments to check for memory leaks with none reported.

The last place I can step into with the debugger after it reports that the "GDB: Interrupted" is this piece of code where NSLogv is invoked:

```
+ (void)print:(NSString *)format, ...
{
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   // Doesn't seem to go past this line
   NSLogv(format, args);                    
   va_end(args);        
}
```

But this method is invoked many a times throughout the app and no problem in any where until at some point after I've used the app long enough.

The stack shown through the debugger thereafter is:

```
#0  0x02592e07 in ___forwarding___
#1  0x02592cd2 in __forwarding_prep_0___
#2  0x000ce57f in _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc
#3  0x0260b00d in __CFStringAppendFormatCore
#4  0x02552f87 in _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux
#5  0x025da36e in _CFLogvEx
#6  0x0014beb5 in NSLogv
```

Upon re-testing over and over again, the SIGKILL consistently happens with the call to NSLogv and no where else.

What else can I turn or set to figure out why the debugger is terminating the instance of the app?

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded? For example, do you use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`, or use `NSThread` directly?

Comment: I use NSOperations at various places and at the point the app gets SIGKILL, it's after I've returned from the runloop using 'performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject'. The NSOperation class passed the object that eventually gets the 'print' called on but the print is happening on the main thread.

Comment: Based on the reference doc for NSLogv, I presumed that it is a thread-safe function and I think I'm using it correctly. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv

Comment: Are you building for the device or simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Check the format string and the arguments supplied are the correct type, for instance with a format string of @"%f" and argument of @"hello", this would crash....